# Upgrade to coroutines 1.6.0 in Kotlin Multiplatform causes iOS crash in Scope.launchIn

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I recently switched my Kotlin Multiplatform Android coroutines library from org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2-native-mt to 1.6.0 which I thought solved the threading issues in 1.5.x. However, now my iOS app, which consumes the Multiplatform library, is crashing on the first occurrence of a coroutine being launched (stack trace below). The code causing the crash is below. What is a resolution to this issue?

The line causing the exception in my multiplatform library is `launchIn()`

```
    TestClass {
        override fun run() {
            myFlow
                .onEach {
                    ...
                }
                .launchIn(Dispatchers.Main)
        }
```

```
 at 0   test                            0x10c51f388        kfun:kotlin.Throwable#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 88 
  at 1   test                            0x10c519286        kfun:kotlin.Exception#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 86 
  at 2   test                            0x10c519476        kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 86 
  at 3   test                            0x10c5199c6        kfun:kotlin.IllegalStateException#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 86 
  at 4   test                            0x10c6aab54        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.takeEventLoop#internal + 388 
  at 5   test                            0x10c6aad03        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.OldDefaultExecutor#dispatch(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext;kotlinx.coroutines.Runnable){} + 179 
  at 6   test                            0x10c6ab211        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.OldMainDispatcher#dispatch(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext;kotlinx.coroutines.Runnable){} + 241 
  at 7   test                            0x10c68e783        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.internal#resumeCancellableWith__at__kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<0:0>(kotlin.Result<0:0>;kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Throwable,kotlin.Unit>?){0§<kotlin.Any?>} + 1091 
  at 8   test                            0x10c69e37b        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics#startCoroutineCancellable__at__kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1<0:0,0:1>(0:0;kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<0:1>;kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Throwable,kotlin.Unit>?){0§<kotlin.Any?>;1§<kotlin.Any?>} + 603 
  at 9   test                            0x10c69e57d        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics#startCoroutineCancellable$default__at__kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1<0:0,0:1>(0:0;kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<0:1>;kotlin.Function1<kotlin.Throwable,kotlin.Unit>?;kotlin.Int){0§<kotlin.Any?>;1§<kotlin.Any?>} + 333 
  at 10  test                            0x10c624883        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart#invoke(kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1<0:0,0:1>;0:0;kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<0:1>){0§<kotlin.Any?>;1§<kotlin.Any?>} + 323 
  at 11  test                            0x10c613edc        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine#start(kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart;0:0;kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1<0:0,1:0>){0§<kotlin.Any?>} + 156 
  at 12  test                            0x10c614139        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines#launch__at__kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext;kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart;kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1<kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope,kotlin.Unit>){}kotlinx.coroutines.Job + 585 
  at 13  test                            0x10c614452        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines#launch$default__at__kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext?;kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart?;kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1<kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope,kotlin.Unit>;kotlin.Int){}kotlinx.coroutines.Job + 626 
  at 14  test                            0x10c688823        kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.flow#launchIn__at__kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<0:0>(kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope){0§<kotlin.Any?>}kotlinx.coroutines.Job + 275 
  at 15  test                            0x10c45672b        kfun:com.test.testshared.device.TestClass#run(){} + 539 
  at 16  test                            0x10c4e206b
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to build.gradle.kts to mark as experimental, and issue resolved:

```
kotlin.targets.withType(KotlinNativeTarget::class.java) {
binaries.all {
    binaryOptions["memoryModel"] = "experimental"
}
```